# Find the length of the marked segment

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry

The question is to find the value of the segment that is marked in purple. The data given in the diagram are the only data given.

[image]

My approach:

I spent approximately 2 hours trying to solve this question. But the only values I found are entered in the diagram below.

[image]

Could anyone please help me to find the correct solution for this question?

(Solutions with less trigonometry are much more appreciated)

Thank you!

Special credits to [@Crna97197085](https://twitter.com/Crna97197085) for presenting this problem on Twitter

Comment: Have you tried cosine law about $\angle\alpha$ into $\triangle(7, 2l, l)$ and $\triangle(3l, 14, 7)$?

Comment: To be honest. I only know sin, cos, and tan in Trigonometry :)

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_cosines

Comment: Thank you. I'll try applying it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

Hint: Use this property that if the measures of arcs JI and JH is $120^o$ the cord EB connecting their mid points B and E is divided three equal parts by chords JH and JI, in this way we have:

$\angle JOB=60^o$

JO is perpendicular bisector of EB, so $\angle GBO=30^o$. Now you have to show that $GK||BC$, in this case we may write:

$\triangle AGK\sim \triangle ABC$

$\Rightarrow \frac {Gk}{BC}=\frac{AG}{AB}=\frac{2.5}4$

$\Rightarrow GK= \frac {2.5}4\times 7=4.4$

In triangle BGK we have:

$GB=BK$

$BG^2+BK^2-2 BK\times BG\times \cos 30^o=GK^2=4.4^2$

Which gives $GB=8.7$

$AB=\frac{8.7\times 4}{1,5}\approx 24\Rightarrow AE=\frac 64=6$

Power of point A is:

$AD\times AC=AE\times AB$

Plugging valuse we get:

$AC=\frac{6\times 24}{4\sqrt2}=18\sqrt 2$

finally:

$DC=AC-AD=14\sqrt2$

Comment: Thank you very much for your solution!

Comment: @IntrovertFirefly, You"r welcome.